# I have to create a month class in Java

Tags: java

One of the requirements is a `getMonthName` method that returns the name if the month, i.e. January is 1. And a `toString` that returns the month name (String represesentation) , and I'm just worried that there's an easier way for what I'm doing  than this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Month {
    private int monthNum = 0;
    private String monthName;
    String monthOne = "JANUARY";
    String monthTwo = "FEBRUARY";
    String monthThree = "MARCH";
    String monthFour = "APRIL";
    String monthFive = "MAY";
    String monthSix = "JUNE";
    String monthSeven = "JULY";
    String monthEight = "AUGUST";
    String monthNine = "SEPTEMBER";
    String monthTen = "OCTOBER";
    String monthEleven = "NOVEMBER";
    String monthTwelve = "DECEMBER";
    //CONSTRUCTORS  
    public Month() 
    {
        monthNum = 1;
    }   
    public Month(int monthNum)
    {
        this.monthNum = monthNum;
        if ((monthNum > 12) || (monthNum <1))
        {
            monthNum = 1;
        }
    }   
    public Month(String monthOne, String monthTwo, String monthThree, String monthFour, String monthFive, String monthSix, String monthSeven, 
            String monthEight, String monthNine, String monthTen, String monthEleven, String monthTwelve)
    {
        monthName.toUpperCase();

        if (monthName.equals(monthOne))
        {
            monthNum = 1;
        }
        else if (monthName.equals(monthTwo))
        {
            monthNum = 2;   
        }
        else if (monthName.equals(monthThree))
        {
            monthNum = 3;
        }
        else if (monthName.equals(monthFour))
        {
            monthNum = 4;
        }
        else if (monthName.equals(monthFive))
        {
            monthNum = 5;
        }
        else if (monthName.equals(monthSix))
        {
            monthNum = 6;
        }
        else if (monthName.equals(monthSeven))
        {
            monthNum = 7;
        }
        else if (monthName.equals(monthEight))
        {
            monthNum = 8;
        }
        else if (monthName.equals(monthNine))
        {
            monthNum = 9;
        }
        else if (monthName.equals(monthTen))
        {
            monthNum = 10;
        }
        else if (monthName.equals(monthEleven))
        {
            monthNum = 11;
        }
        else 
        {
            monthNum = 12;
        }
    }


    //METHODS
    public void setMonthNum(int monthNum)
    {
        this.monthNum = monthNum;
        if ((monthNum >12) || (monthNum<1))
        {
            monthNum = 1;
        }
    }

    public int getMonthNumber()
    {
        return monthNum;
    }

    public String getMonthName()
    {
        if (monthNum == 1)
        {
            return "January";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 2)
        {
            return "February";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 3)
        {
            return "March";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 4)
        {
            return "April";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 5)
        {
            return "May";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 6)
        {
            return "June";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 7)
        {
            return "July";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 8)
        {
            return "August";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 9)
        {
            return "September";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 10)
        {
            return "October";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 11)
        {
            return "November";
        }
        else 
        {
            return "December";
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        if (monthNum == 1)
        {
            return "January";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 2)
        {
            return "February";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 3)
        {
            return "March";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 4)
        {
            return "April";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 5)
        {
            return "May";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 6)
        {
            return "June";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 7)
        {
            return "July";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 8)
        {
            return "August";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 9)
        {
            return "September";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 10)
        {
            return "October";
        }
        else if (monthNum == 11)
        {
            return "November";
        }
        else 
        {
            return "December";
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or is this the best way at my level to do this?

Comment: Yeah, probably look into an array.  For example, `month[11]="November";`

Comment: Or use an enum.

Comment: Any time you have a list of variables with names like `somethingOne`, `somethingTwo`, `somethingThree`, ..., that's a clear sign that you need to be thinking about arrays.  (Or some other collection object.)

Comment: Have a look at `java.time.Month` if you're using 1.8+

Comment: **The method `setMonthNum(int)` does not work correctly, you can pass 13 to the instance because you correct only a locale variable in the check, you correct not the field-value!**

Answer (score 1):

If you must implement a Month class yourself then look into [enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), otherwise
check out the docs for [java.time.Month](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) – Try something like this...

```
import java.time.Month;

public Month getMonthName( int monthNum )
{
    return Month.of( monthNum );
}
```

Or simply...

```
System.out.println( Month.of( monthNumber ) );
```

Comment: I am pretty sure it is some sort of school assignment, so using built-in standard classes will not meet the requirements

Comment: Yea I wanted to go about doing that, but I do have to build it myself

Comment: OK in that case look at enums (link provided at the top of my answer). This is a textbook case in which you could be using them

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions to improve your class:

1. use KeyValuePair(example, [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)) to store the month list, since, it would be easy to maintain and retrieve information.
2. If you use keyValuePair collection you can access the month using id directly rather than using nested if statements.(as you did in getMonthName() and toString() method)

Answer (score 0):

It is simply

```
class Month {

    private static String monthNames[] = {
        "January", "February", "March", 
        "April", "May", "June", "July", 
        "August", "September", "October", 
        "November", "December"};

    private int monthNumber;

    public Month(int n) {

        if (n < 1 || n > 12) {
            monthNumber = 1;
        } else {
            monthNumber = n;
        }
    }

    public String getMonthName() {
        return monthNumber[monthNumber - 1];
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getMonthName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you could use is HashMap where key would be the month's number and value is its name. Using HashMap you can also get the key based on the value and vice-versa which seems you want to do. 
Also try avoiding too much else ifs. You can use **switch** instead.